# alocação de memoria dinamica em structs

Tags: c

Estou tentando aloca uma struct com a funcao malloc isolando o codigo dela pra uma funcao separada, mas por algum motivo nao quer funcionar, se eu deixar o codigo dentro da main, sem isolar, funciona normalmente.
exemplo tentando isolar para uma funcao, que nao esta funcionando:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct{
    int inteiro;
    float numero;
    char nome[5];
}teste;


void aloca(teste *ptr, int tamanho){
    ptr = malloc(sizeof(teste)*tamanho);
}
int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    teste*agora;

    aloca(agora, 5);
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        agora[i].inteiro = rand()%5;
        printf("%d\n", agora[i].inteiro);
    }
}
```

exemplo sem isolar, que esta funcionando

```
    #include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct{
    int inteiro;
    float numero;
    char nome[5];
}teste;



int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    teste*agora;

    agora = malloc(sizeof(agora)*5);
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        agora[i].inteiro = rand()%5;
        printf("%d\n", agora[i].inteiro);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Em seu código `agora` é `teste*` e só existe em `main`. Quando cria a função deve simplesmente retornar o endereço. De nada adianta passar o ponteiro para a função se o valor dele não voltar para que possa ser usado.
No geral evite `void`. Em geral é um erro ou desperdício.
E use alguma convenção para os nomes de estruturas, como usar a primeira letra em maiúscula...

Prefira

```
Teste* aloca(size_t tamanho)
{
    return (Teste*)malloc(sizeof(Teste) * tamanho);
}
```

E use assim

```
    Teste* agora = aloca(5);
```

E no melhor estilo `RAII` de `C++` escreva já a função que libera a área alocada e já retorne `NULL` para poder invalidar o ponteiro na mesma linha.

```
Teste* libera(Teste* p)
{
    free(p);
    return NULL;
};
```

Para poder escrever

```
int main(void)
{
    srand((unsigned) time(NULL));
    Teste* agora = aloca(5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        agora[i].inteiro = rand() % 5;
        printf("%d\n", agora[i].inteiro);
    }
    agora = libera(agora);
    return 0;
}
```

De modo a não ter um ponteiro não inicializado ou inválido em lugar nenhum. Nem todos seus programas vão ter 15 linhas entãqo é bom criar esse tipo de hábito.

No geral entenda que o que quer mesmo é usar encapsulamento e colocar o tamanho da área na estrutura. Assim não vai ter que mudar no programa todo toda vez. E assim vai menos chances ainda de erro.

#### Considere

```
typedef struct
{
    size_t   tam;
    Teste*   D;

}   Bloco;
```

#### E esse exemplo

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct
{
    int   inteiro;
    float numero;
    char  nome[5];
} Teste;

typedef struct
{
    size_t   tam;
    Teste*   D;
} Bloco;

Bloco* aloca(size_t);
Bloco* libera(Bloco*);

int main(void)
{
    srand(220730);
    Bloco* agora = aloca(5);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < agora->tam; i++)
    {
        agora->D[i].inteiro = rand() % 5;
        printf("%d\n", agora->D[i].inteiro);
    }
    agora = libera(agora);
    return 0;
}

Bloco* aloca(size_t tamanho)
{
    Bloco* b = malloc(sizeof(Bloco));
    b->tam   = tamanho;
    b->D = (Teste*)malloc(sizeof(Teste) * tamanho);
    return b;
}

Bloco* libera(Bloco* p)
{
    free(p->D);
    free(p);
    return NULL;
};
```

- use `unsigned` ou `size_t` quando sabe que o valor não pode ser negativo. Assim nunca terá que testar o sinal.
- considere que em geral não quer enquanto testa usar algo como `time(NULL)` em `srand`. Use uma constante.